# How to set a variable name with dynamic variables?

Tags: twig

I am trying to set variables with dynamic names. The code I am using is:

```
{% for i in 0..2 %}
    {% set foo~i    = 'array'.'~i~'.'getfoo' %}
    {% set bar~i    = 'array'.'~i~'.'getbar' %}
{% endfor %}
```

The variables I want are:
foo0
bar0
foo1
bar1
foo2
bar2

But I get this error `Unexpected token "operator" of value "~" ("end of statement block" expected)`

Also I don't want these variables as array.

Comment: Can't be done by vanilla `twig`, you'd need an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @DarkBee mentioned, you can't do this in vanilla Twig. But you can create quite a simple extension – notice that `$context` needs to be passed by reference:

```
class MyTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension {
    public function getFunctions() {
        return [
            new Twig_Function('set', [$this, 'set'], ['needs_context' => true]),
        ];
    }

    public function set(&$context, $name, $value) {
        $context[$name] = $value;
    }
}
$twig->addExtension(new MyTwigExtension());
```

Then in Twig you can do:

```
{{ dump() }}
{% do set('foo' ~ 1, 'bar') %}
{{ dump() }}
```

The above will print:

```
array(0) {
}

array(1) {
  ["foo1"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

But note that a `for` loop has its own context. So if you do this:

```
{% set foo = 'bar' %}

Before loop:
{{ dump() }}

{% for i in 0..2 %}
    {%- do set('foo' ~ i, 'iteration ' ~ i) %}
    {%- if loop.last %}
        {{- 'Inside loop (last iteration):\n' }}
        {{- loop.last ? dump() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

After loop:
{{ dump() }}
```

You get this – notice the `_parent` array which represents the "parent" context outside of the loop:

```
Before loop:
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}


Inside loop (last iteration):
array(9) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["_parent"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
  ["_seq"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["loop"]=>
  array(8) {
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["foo"]=>
      string(3) "bar"
    }
    ["index0"]=>
    int(2)
    ["index"]=>
    int(3)
    ["first"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["revindex0"]=>
    int(0)
    ["revindex"]=>
    int(1)
    ["length"]=>
    int(3)
    ["last"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["i"]=>
  int(2)
  ["_key"]=>
  int(2)
  ["foo0"]=>
  string(11) "iteration 0"
  ["foo1"]=>
  string(11) "iteration 1"
  ["foo2"]=>
  string(11) "iteration 2"
}


After loop:
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

You can overcome this limitation in three ways. First is to initialize the variables before the `for` loop (notice that `foo0` is left as `null` because the loop starts at `1`, and that `foo3` won't be in the global context because it hasn't been initialized):

```
{% set foo0 = null %}
{% set foo1 = null %}
{% set foo2 = null %}

{% for i in 1..3 %}
    {% do set('foo' ~ i, 'iteration ' ~ i) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ dump() }}
```

The above will print:

```
array(3) {
  ["foo0"]=>
  NULL
  ["foo1"]=>
  string(11) "iteration 1"
  ["foo2"]=>
  string(11) "iteration 2"
}
```

The second way is to modify the extension's `set` method to check whether `$context` contains a key `_parent`:

```
public function set(&$context, $name, $value) {
    $context[$name] = $value;

    if (array_key_exists('_parent', $context)) {
        $this->set($context['_parent'], $name, $value);
    }
}
```

Then even nested `for` loops aren't a problem:

```
{% for i in 1..2 %}
    {% for j in 3..4 %}
        {% do set('foo' ~ i ~ j, i ~ ' and ' ~ j) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{{ dump() }}
```

The above will print:

```
array(4) {
  ["foo13"]=>
  string(7) "1 and 3"
  ["foo14"]=>
  string(7) "1 and 4"
  ["foo23"]=>
  string(7) "2 and 3"
  ["foo24"]=>
  string(7) "2 and 4"
}
```

The third way is to keep the extension's `set` method intact and create a new method, e.g. `set_global`:

```
class MyTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension {
    public function getFunctions() {
        return [
            new Twig_Function('set',        [$this, 'set'],        ['needs_context' => true]),
            new Twig_Function('set_global', [$this, 'set_global'], ['needs_context' => true]),
        ];
    }

    public function set(&$context, $name, $value) {
        $context[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function set_global(&$context, $name, $value) {
        $context[$name] = $value;

        if (array_key_exists('_parent', $context)) {
            return $this->set_global($context['_parent'], $name, $value);
        }
    }
}
$twig->addExtension(new MyTwigExtension());
```

Then you can use `set` to set variables in the current context (e.g. in the context of a `for` loop) or `set_global` to set "global" variables (in the context of the file). You can use both methods inside `for` loops to set new values to already initialized variables.