# Twig print available from string

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-filter

How to print available form string in twig
In my code php

```
$data['fruits'] = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
$data['help_apple'] = 'This is help apple';
$data['help_banana'] = 'This is help for banana';
$data['help_orange'] = 'This is help for orange';
```

In twig template

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
{{ "help_" ~ fruit }}
{% endfor %}
```

The print screen is help_apple, help_banana, help_orange
How to print correct data i need for help_ fruit key ?

Comment: You are WAY better making a twig extension rather than hacking twig syntax. Then just pass fruit in to your twig method, and do what you do in PHP, returning whatever output you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the attribute function with _context. Tested on twigfiddle.com. Hope this helps.

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
    {# Here is how you do it #}
    {{ attribute(_context, 'help_'~ fruit) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can i set attribute context like {% set attribute(_context, 'help_'~ fruit, "this is set context value") %}

Comment: Not sure what the goal is. Can you give me an example of what your are trying to do?

Comment: You may want to restructure the array if that's possible. The you can use set to change the values of the help_ array keys. For example,

    `$data['help']['help_apple'] = 'This is help apple';`

Answer (score 0):

The `_context` variable holds all variables in the current context. Instead of using the [`attribute` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html), you can access values of the `_context` array with the regular bracket notation as well:

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
    {{ _context['help_' ~ fruit] }}
{% endfor %}
```

I would personally do it this way as it's more concise and in my opinion clearer.

You might want to check for undefined variables when accessing values of the `_context` array. I have written about it in my answer to this question: [Symfony2 - How to access dynamic variable names in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/symfony2-how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig/48543281#48543281).

---

You also asked whether something like this is possible:

```
{% set attribute(context, 'help' ~ fruit, "value") %}
```

That's not possible. If you want to set variables with dynamic names, you need to create a Twig extension. Take a look at my answer to this question: [How to set a variable name with dynamic variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522418/how-to-set-a-variable-name-with-dynamic-variables/48547463)

But, like @user9189147 mentioned, it would be easier and in my opinion clearer if you instead created a new array to hold the help values. Then you wouldn't need to create an extension.

```
$data['fruits'] = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];
$data['help']   = [];
$data['help']['apple']  = 'This is help apple';
$data['help']['banana'] = 'This is help for banana';
$data['help']['orange'] = 'This is help for orange';
```

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
    {{ help[fruit] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then you can set new values to the help values in Twig using the [`merge` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html), like this (though I don't know why you would want to do it in Twig):

```
{# Set single value #}
{% set help = help|merge({
    banana: 'New help for banana',
}) %}

{# Or multiple values #}
{% set help = help|merge({
    apple:  'An apple a day keeps the doctor away',
    orange: 'Orange is the new black',
}) %}
```